# Integrating Amazon & eBay orders into Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been racking my head for the last couple of days and can't seem to think how this would work. I am trying to integrate our eBay and Amazon store to Woocommerce to send any eBay and Amazon orders directly into Woocommerce.

I am trying not to use any third party products to do this.

Can anyone help me or give me any pointers?

Comment: I would like to suggest you RTFM (ofc) and take a look on open source solutions (if they are exist). Understanding how open source third party works - will lead you to way how to sort it out.

Comment: @victorPerov unfortunately I cannot seem to find an Open Source solution, even looked on GITHub to no luck!

Comment: I was told by [woocomerce official site](https://woocommerce.com/products/amazon-ebay-integration/) that it's free. Could you check it again?

Comment: That's for Woocommerce.com which is their hosted solution (Like shopify) I've got wordPress and Woocommerce self hosted

Answer (score 0):

If you want full integration (products, stock, orders etc.) of woocommerce and ebay amazon marketplaces, I don't think there is "really" no free solution out there. There are two plugins (one for each marketplace): WP-Lister for eBay comes in free and pro(paid) versions, and WP-Lister Pro for Amazon only paid version, but I have not tried either of them.

Instead, I opted for CODISTO, recommended by woocommerce but it is a SAAS, costing around $50 per month. So far it looks good. I will test it out further within the 1 month trial, and post the results here if anyone still interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option available right now.

The API for the orders is available but for that, you will need an expert developer to manage all this.
If you want we can do this for you and help you out in overcoming from this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54839394/